# Books for Algebra and linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus

Which book one (who do not have teacher or instructor ) should have to prefer for algebra and linear algebra. The book should have to be self introductory, lucid and with more solved example.

Comment: Horn, Roger A., and Charles R. Johnson. Matrix analysis. Cambridge university press, 2012.

Answer (score 1):

There is a big difference between linear algebra and abstract algebra. For the first one, a very good source is Schaum's linear algebra - it has all the solved examples you can dream of, and if you go through this book once, you really know linear algebra. For Abstract Algebra, considered more advanced than linear algebra, I would opt for Dummit and Foote - one of the best textbooks available.

Comment: In algebra I want to read group theory, ring.

Comment: I am going to read it (group theory and ring first time without any teacher or instructor so please suggest me books in regard of said constraints.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look on Gilbert strang for linear algebra ,there are lectures available online.And for Abstract algebra "Contemporary Abstract Algebra
Book by Joseph Gallian" will be a very good resource for self learning.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestion